# Calculate multiple div Positions with same id

Tags: jquery, position

I have a slight problem.
I have multiple divs with the same id, what i want to do is when i hover over the div it will expand in height. but i have the problem when it does, it pushes the other divs below it down.

So i thought of a solution with jquery, if i could calculate the position of the current element when i hover over it then i could use those values and change the div to position: absolute with those values. and back to the normal state when the mouse leaves.
The problem now it only calculates the position of the first div in the markup when i hover over it. and when i hover over the others it doesnt calculate.

I dont want to number the divs with different Id/classes because it will be an automated system with new divs being added etc.

maybe it can be done in another way? im pretty new to jquery so this is what i came up with.

Wall of text sorry D: any help is appreciated!

Markup `

```
<div id="content-element">
        <div class="element-container">
            <div class="top-info">
                <img src="phone-placeholder.png" alt="placeholder" width="65px" height="58px"/>
                <div class="bg-circle"></div>
                <h3>eerste maand</h3>
                <span><h4>&#8364;12.5</h4></span>
                <h3>Daarna</h3>
                <span><h4>&#8364;12.5</h4></span>
            </div>
            <p>Telefoon abonemment met Telefoon</p>
            <p><span>100</span> Bel & SMS <span>500mb</span></p>
            <p><span> Jr</span> telefoon abonnement</p>
            <p>Prijs Telefoon: <span>Gratis</span></p>
            <p>Telefoon abonemment met Telefoon</p>
            <p><span>100</span> Bel & SMS <span>500mb</span></p>
            <p><span> Jr</span> telefoon abonnement</p>
            <p>Prijs Telefoon: <span>Gratis</span></p>
            <p>Telefoon abonemment met Telefoon</p>
            <p><span>100</span> Bel & SMS <span>500mb</span></p>
            <p><span> Jr</span> telefoon abonnement</p>
            <p>Prijs Telefoon: <span>Gratis</span></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end content-element-->   
</div><!-- end content-container -->`
```

jQuery

```
$('#content-element').mouseenter(function () {
        var $positionTop =  $(this).children('.element-container').position().top;
        var $positionLeft = $(this).children('.element-container').position().left;
        console.log($positionTop);
        console.log($positionLeft);
});
$('#content-element').mouseleave(function () {
        var $positionTop =  $(this).children('.element-container').position().top;
        var $positionLeft = $(this).children('.element-container').position().left;
        console.log($positionTop);
        console.log($positionLeft);
});
```

Comment: Never have multiple elements with the same ID. It's illegal in the real world and should be illegal in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and set position: absolute; on the div's

```
#yourDIVid {
```

position: absolute;

}

Comment: this is not what i want, the divs are floated next to eachother, i want to change the postition to absolute when i hover over the current div. so that they can expand without pushing the other divs down.

Comment: Have you tried z-index property? Like when you hover, you set z-index to greater value than the divs that you dont want to move.
Or you could try to set position: absolute on the divs that you dont want to be moved. OR try position: fixed; then they certainly wont move :)

Comment: i have not i will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there should not be multiple blocks with the same id.

But if you want to select the multiple divs with the same id you can use

```
$('div#content-element') 
OR
$('body').find('#content-element')
```